# Почему эта строчка является вирусом для Касперского?

Tags: delphi, вирусы

Код из листинга (Delphi):
`SendMessage(WindowFromPoint(Mouse.CursorPos),EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR,0,0);`
Касперский сразу визжит и пишет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что в этом коде не так? Почему он считается вирусом?

Comment: Сколько я имел дело с касперским, мне кажется что это вообще не антивирус... А вот как собрать 30 ГБ инфы о пользователе, это запросто, и причём данную фичу не отрубить.

а строчку скорее всего опознаёт как вирус только потому. что подобный набор битов встречался в вирусняках. Скан довольно тупая вещь, он просто проверяет на совпадение с бд вирусов.

Answer (score 1):

Данное сообщение позволяет сделать из поля ввода со звездочками обычное поле ввода, таким образом узнав введенный пароль. Этим пользуется ряд программ.

Поэтому Касперский и ругается.